# How to display error message if the ajax return 0 result from sql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax4jsf, error-messages-for

Im trying to display an error message to saying that , When result is 0 from database (mysql) 
 that will be an error message.

The code below im trying to use ajax to get SQL result and when it return 0 error will be display.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "charts/prod.php?year=" + $("#selectyear").val() + "&month=" + $("#selectmonth").val(),
  dataType: "json", // serializes the form's elements.
  success: function (result) { 
  var chart = c3.generate({
       bindto: '#piepie',
       data: result.value,
       color: { 
         pattern: ['#f35213', '#f1af4c'] },
         pie: { title: "Productivity", }
     });

  },
  error: function() {

        if (result.percentage==undefined){ 
  alert ('Data are not ready yet!!');  
} else {
alert(result.percentage);
}
}   
});
```

Comment: Is there a problem? The code you posted doesn't check for zero anywhere.

Comment: @Charlie I dint check for zero as the result I got is this like, {"percentage":[]} empty result.
So I would like to pop out an error msg when it returns empty and did not pop out any msg when it got value

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "charts/prod.php?year=" + $("#selectyear").val() + "&month=" + $("#selectmonth").val(),
      dataType: "json", // serializes the form's elements.
      success: function (result) { 
        
        if (result.value == "0"){
          alert ('ERROR!!');  
        } else {
        
         var chart = c3.generate({
           bindto: '#piepie',
           data: result.value,
           color: { 
             pattern: ['#f35213', '#f1af4c'] },
             pie: { title: "Productivity", }
         });
        
        }
      },
      error: function() {
          alert ('Error');  
      } 
});
```

Try this

Comment: my result is empty like this {"percentage":[]}, and I would like to display an error message when it returns empty result

Comment: I changed a little bit. Try that. I do not have your json results so I can not test this. You should be able to just test the value with an if statement checking for 0 or whatever string you want and show an error if true.

Comment: I've tried to paste your codes but no error message pop up.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (result.percentage.length==0){ // THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED.
      alert ('ERROR!!');  
    } else {
     // YOUR CODE GOES HERE.

    }
```

As you have commented you are getting result as '{"percentage":[]}'. So you have percentage property as an array with length 0. So, you need to test that only.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: So, that means you have percentage as undefined and not array. So you can check result.percentage==undefined .
Also, you should paste your response when asking question. You can get you response logged in console of browser using console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

Comment: When I got the result like this, {"percentage":["0.0","0.0","-50.0","-50.0","0.0","100.0"],"new":"0","pending":"0","completed":"1","ongoing":"1","delay":"1","prod":"14"}
it also pop up the error message

Comment: I only want to pop up the error message when percentage= undefined and I dunwan any pop up msg for percentage=value

Comment: use == sign to compare.   you have to write if(result.percentage==undefined){ alert("ERROR"); }
else { /* CODE */ }

Comment: if (result.percentage==undefined){ 
      alert ('Data are not ready yet!!');  
    } else {
        
         var chart = c3.generate({
           bindto: '#piepie',
           data: result.value,
           color: { 
             pattern: ['#f35213', '#f1af4c'] },
             pie: { title: "Productivity", }
         });

Comment: Please paste the code that you used to test undefined..  I think you have made accidental assignment.

Comment: ACCORDING TO YOUR JSON   {"percentage":["0.0","0.0","-50.0","-50.0","0.0","100.0"],"n‌​ew":"0","pending":"0‌​","completed":"1","o‌​ngoing":"1","delay":‌​"1","prod":"14"}  THE CODE 
   
 
if (result.percentage==undefined){ alert ('Data are not ready yet!!'); } will only fire alert when you don't get data. Other wise it wont fire.. TRY IT AGAIN. AND IF YOU CODE IS IN A JS FILE THEN TRY REMOVING BROWSER CACHE.

Comment: I've pasted my updated code in my question.
It still fire alert when i get data

Comment: Yes I've removed browser cache

Comment: add       alert(result.percentage);       before 
    if (result.percentage==undefined){        so, you will know what browser is considering for your result.percentage. NOW you need to test both the cases 1) with proper result 2) improper result. And you will know what you need to test...

Comment: I've updated my code again in my question 
For now, it did not show error msg for both got value and undefined value but for undefined value it does not display pie chart

Comment: you cannot code in **error** section of ajax as you are not throwing exception from backend. If you set exception header on server side. Then only you will receive call back in error. You have to code in your success callback.

Comment: you have **result.value**

Comment: If I code in success callback, it will show error msg in both success and undefined value

Comment: this is because you  have **result.value** and not result.percentage...am i correct???

Comment: yes
So how to pop up errror only when it return undefined

Comment: if (result == undefined){
    //display error message 
}

Comment: When I used pragun code, It will display msg for both undefined and value result.
And my pie chart disappear for both testing

Comment: if(result==undefined || result.value==undefined){

Comment: i will leave now. hope you find answer. If you are done please mark answer correct and close question.

Comment: Okay. I'm not yet success. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
if ((typeof result !== " undefined") && (result !== null) && (result == 0)){
    alert("YourErrorMessageHere"); 
}
```

Comment: I want to display error msg when it returns undefined/null/0

Comment: I've modified the content a bit and maybe you can choose using something other such a bootstrap modal to display the error message. Hope this works for you!

Comment: When the result is [["More than 85%",null],["Less than 85%",0]], I want to display error else no error

Comment: so like tis? if (result.More than 85% == "null"){
          alert ('ERROR!!');  
        } else {

Comment: It will not show any error msg when result is {"value":{"columns":[["More than 85%","14"],["Less than 85%",64]],"type":"pie"}}

Comment: It will not show any error msg when result is {"value":{"columns":[["More than 85%","14"],["Less than 85%",64]],"type":"pie"}}
and it will show error msg when the result is {"value":{"columns":[["More than 85%",null],["Less than 85%",0]],"type":"pie"}}